# If it's a page lead, I'll normally try to get hold of it

Tags: conditionals, modal-verbs, will-would

1. If it's a page lead, I'**ll normally try** to get hold of it. If it's a summary I **normally won't have** time.
2. I **would normally read** abstract and discussion, and skim the rest. If it's about quantum mechanics, there's really not much point in me reviewing the calculations …
3. **Ideally**, we'**d read** all papers and phone the scientists. But, sometimes, it's 6pm and you have an hour to turn around 600 words. Then, choices become rather limited.
   (https://www.theguardian.com/science/blog/2012/mar/28/science-jounalists-read-papers-stories)

a) If it's a page lead, I **normally try** to get hold of it. If it's a summary I **normally don't have** time.

b) I **normally read** abstract and discussion, and skim the rest. If it's about quantum mechanics, there's really not much point in me reviewing the calculations …

c) **Ideally**, we **read** all papers and phone the scientists. But, sometimes, it's 6pm and you have an hour to turn around 600 words. Then, choices become rather limited.

Sentences (1), (2) and (3) imply what the speaker **will/would** **normally/ideally** do *in particular circumstances*.

Q: Have those circumstances already arisen? If so, then what is the use of "will" or "would" here? Why not simply use sentences (a), (b) and (c) instead? In other words, does "**will/would normally** do it" indicate that the speaker has already done it, maybe once, maybe several times in the past?

Comment: It's a description of a normal tendency, that's all. One can assume the speaker has done it in the past and expects to continue; that's the usual situation for generics like this.

Comment: Someone who is asked to describe their day might begin, "Normally I get up at..." or "Normally I'll get up at..." They mean the same. The start of the third quotation, "Ideally, we'd read all papers...", is roughly equivalent to "If we had all the time in the world we'd....." The *If* requires the conditional "would". But they're all describing their normal routine.

Comment: Sentence 3 really shows you what's going on. In that case the speaker is describing the preferred course of action but saying that under a specific set of circumstances taking that course of action is impossible. All the sentences work in similar ways, they are referring to the normal or preferred courses of action, but each one gives an example of a set of circumstances where that course cannot be taken. Neither part of any of the sentences refers directly to a specific case, they are all generalisations.

Comment: You all say sentences (1), (2) and (3), using "will" or "would", are generalizations. Is that a specific use, a characteristic of the word "will/would"? I ask this because I've always known them to refer to *real/hypothetical future time*. But do they also talk about *past events*?